# CSS animation of text and other stuff

Tags: css, animation

Looking at http://www.css3maker.com/ I see the menu items like "Border Radius" getting animated on mouseover. How was this achieved using CSS?

Comment: Not css, they using  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: @Pablo oops, somehow I thought they were using CSS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS animations can be done using the transition property.
Check http://www.css3creations.com/ for demos.

Answer (score 4):

I did not look how it was done in that website. But [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) can do wonders with animation. It's a javascript API that is becoming widely used.